# $.getJSON function executed after everything else

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I'm using the following code:

```
function eventListenerTest(event) {
    if (document.getElementById('gem_cvo_select_list')) {
        var address;
        $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
            address = data.rows[0];
            alert("This gets executed afterwards");
        });
        alert("This gets executed first");
        event.infoWindowHtml = "<b>Address: </b>" + address;
    }
}
```

Problem is the $.getJSON function gets executed after the 'address' variable is used in the infoWindow. Modified the code like this:

```
function eventListenerTest(event) {
    if (document.getElementById('gem_cvo_select_list')) {
        var address;
        $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
            address = data.rows[0];
            event.infoWindowHtml = "<b>Address: </b>" + address;
        });
    }
}
```

The 'event' object doesn't seem to be accessible this way (nothing is displayed in the Google Maps infoWindow). I figured I should be able to pass 'event' to the function inside the JSON but I have no idea how to accomplish this.

Comment: Look into asynchronous code execution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function eventListenerTest(event, callback) {
    if (document.getElementById('gem_cvo_select_list')) {
        var address;
        $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
            address = data.rows[0];
            event.infoWindowHtml = "<b>Address: </b>" + address;
            callback();
        });
    }
}
```

Then:

```
eventListenerTest(event, function(){
     // you will use updated event object here
});
```

Comment: I don't see how that would help - the `event` parameter will be available the same as your new `_event` variable (they'll both end up in the same closure). I imagine the problem is that this is an event handler and by the time the async `$.getJSON()` callback is executed the event handler has finished execution so it's too late to set properties of the `event` object.

Answer (score 0):

You should use $.proxy method to make sure that the callback function that gets executed keeps the context of the function creating the Ajax call.

Updated Javascript:

```
function eventListenerTest(event) {
    if (document.getElementById('gem_cvo_select_list')) {
        var address;
        $.getJSON(url, $.proxy(function (data) {
            address = data.rows[0];
            event.infoWindowHtml = "<b>Address: </b>" + address;
        },this));
    }
}
```

More information: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/

Comment: That won't help, because he's not using `this` anywhere

Comment: I think it will work.  The function being proxied inherits the context of eventListenerTest.  The context of the function is more then just "this" and should contain "event".

Comment: I just wrote a small test, and my definition of the $.proxy method is correct.  The code in my answer will work.

Comment: Sadly, it doesn't work here. The default infoWindow text gets displayed before the new text is set.

Comment: The function passed to `$.getJSON()` _without_ `$.proxy()` (as shown in the question) already has access to the variables of the `eventListenerTest()` function including the `event` parameter. You _don't_ need `$.proxy()` for that. (As blockhead indicated, you really don't need `$.proxy()` except when you need a fixed `this` within a function.) Regarding the small test you wrote, obviously I don't know exactly what you did, but if you try the code in your answer without `$.proxy()` it will work the same...